# Stereochemistry of product in Grignard-Gilman addition reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry, grignard-reagent

I would like to know whether the stereochemistry given in the following reaction is correct or not?
[image]

Which attack is more likely? axial or equatorial? I think I should say pseudo axial or pseudo equatorial....since there is a double bond in the ring.
[image]

Am I missing anything here...?

Ok. I am adding what I got from other forum, though I do not follow it properly.
[image]

Comment: You don't seem to be considering the relevant factors. After conjugate addition, the stereochemistry is under diastereoselectively controlled. You should consider the protonation step instead.

Comment: I have an answer prepared for you but it won't be posted until you make an effort to address the problem. What does the enolate look like after addition as Zhe has hinted?

Comment: Look for a relaxed cyclohexene structure an go from there.

Comment: ok user5519, I have added an image, though it is not my work.

Answer (score 3):

I have supplied a diagram that is more legible than the small one you have provided. The cis stereochemistry of the product is a function of axial, but not equatorial attack of the reagent. The stereochemistry is established after the addition occurs. Structures **1** and **2** illustrate the "chair-chair" interconversions of the cyclohexene ring. As the C-C bond is being formed by axial addition in **1**, the carbon bearing the red p-orbital will rehybridize from sp<sup>2</sup> to sp<sup>3</sup> during the transition state (TS) for bond formation. This transition state (TS) will lead to enolate **3** through a low energy, chair-like pathway. 
Alternatively, TS **2** would proceed through a higher energy, twist boat-like TS. Both routes occur through axial attack with **1** ---> **3** prevailing over **2** ---> **4**. Enolate **3** is in equilibrium with enolate **5**, which is unfavored by what is known as an [allylic A<sup>1,3</sup>](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00951a046) interaction.<sup>1</sup> The critical step is the kinetic protonation of enolate **3** on workup. Protonation of enolate **3** on carbon from the underside of the double bond (remote from the phenyl group) again occurs through a chair-like TS. Protonation on the top of the double bond would occur through a twist boat-like TS. This pathway is higher in energy and would have provided the trans isomer **9**. 
Structures **6** and **7** are the two chair conformers of the cis-isomer. If one uses to vigorous a set of conditions upon workup, enolization of **6** and **7** can lead reversibly to enol **8** and eventually to the thermodynamic isomer **9**.

[image]

1) Johnson, F., Malhotra, S. K., *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1965**, *87*, 5492.

Comment: There is no such thing as rehybridisation. 1, 2 are twist conformers, they don't resemble either boat or chair. And a few paragraphs certainly would help readability.

Comment: Yes, 2 is a twist. Let's remember who the audience is. Be nice!

Comment: It does not matter who the audience is, what is wrong is wrong. And are you really telling me to be nice? What was it in my comment that was offensive to you?

Comment: The point of talking about rehybridization was to illustrate that during the TS the carbon goes from sp2 to sp3. Peace.

Comment: What if attack of H on either 3 or 5 from the top rather than from the bottom as shown by you.........?

Comment: If protonation of 3 or 5 (equatorial?) were to occur on the "top", the trans isomer 9 would form. The kinetic product is cis, not trans.